# Find all triples satisfying an equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, egyptian-fractions

Another question I saw recently:

> Find all triples of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=1$.

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because just like [every other question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/338209/blastzit?tab=questions), you show no effort whatsoever in attempting to answer it on your own. Asking 'Can anyone help me with it?' is simply not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\frac{1}{n}>0$ for all natural $n$, all of $a,b,c$ have to be at least two.
Let $a\leq b\leq c$. Unless $a=b=c=3$, $a=2$. Then we have $\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{1}{2}$, so similarly either $b=c=4$ or $b=3$. In the latter case, we get $c=6$.
So, $(a,b,c)=(3,3,3),(2,4,4),(2,3,6)$ are all the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Without loss of generality, let $a<b<c$ and set $t=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$.

- If $a=1$ then $t>1$
- If $a\ge 3$ then $t<1$

Thus $a=2$

Comment: Generality *is* lost in assuming that $a,b,c$ are all distinct, as the list of solutions in another answer indicates.

Comment: @Karl Kronenfeldyes  trivial solution is $(3,3,3)$